# Telligent 10 - Velocity Template - get current datetime

Tags: velocity, vtl, telligent, velocity-template-language

Using Telligent 10 platform and their native Velocity Template Language, how can we simply get the current `datetime`?

Per the many examples I've seen here on SO these first two require the `$date` var previously defined and those examples all define the date statically not by getting the current system datetime so the following do not work:

```
#set ($today = $date.getCurrentDate()) 
<span>$today</span>

#set ($today = $date.getDate()) 
<span>$today</span>
```

Per [this Telligent Community thread](https://community.telligent.com/community/archive/f/developer-forum/1074279/date-operations) I read that Telligent uses .NET DateTime (of which I'm very familiar) but ... these don't work either in Widget Studio:

```
#set ($today = DateTime.Now)
<span>$today</span>

#set ($today = new DateTime)
<span>$today.Now</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I overlooked the properties (literally the first section) outlined for the [`$core_v2_utility`](https://community.telligent.com/community/9/w/api-documentation/51036/core-v2-utility-widget-extension).

We can get the current date by using the following:

```
$core_v2_utility.CurrentDate
```